# gWidgets gfile: Directing User to a folder in the browser pop-up

Tags: browser, gwidgets

I'm creating a GUI with R and I want to improve the gfile directory selector.

I'm trying to add an argument so that, when the browse window appears, it has preselected a part of the path.

I.e.
when

```
select.button <- gbutton("Select", container=win, handler = function(h,...) {
```

selection <- gfile(type = c ("selectdir"))

})

is activated I want the pop-up to show subfolders in a particular folder(frex the desktop).

I think that the filter argument is what I need(as per the manual cited below), but I can't quite make it work.

[filter
Filter for files shown during selection.  Can be nested list, as in example or a
named character vector with the names a description and value a file extension
(no dots) of files endings to match.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/gWidgets.pdf)

I've also tried initial.dir with the following combinations:

```
selection <- gfile(type = c ("selectdir"), initial.dir="/home/robert")
selection <- gfile(type = c ("selectdir"), initial.dir="/home/robert/")
selection <- gfile(type = c ("selectdir"), initial.dir="/home/robert/R/")
selection <- gfile(type = c ("selectdir"), initial.dir="home/robert/R/")
selection <- gfile(type = c ("selectdir"), initial.dir=(/home/robert/R/))
```

Comment: Try setting 'initial.dir'

Comment: Hello, I've been trying intial.dir but so far no luck. I should say I'm running under Linux, R 3.2.4

Comment: Can you post your command? It works for me locally.

Comment: Looking at the above,  it works with `RGtk2`. But on `tcltk` the combination of `selectdir` and `initial.dir` is broken. I'll file an issue.